# ticket machine in netbeans

Tags: java, object

I need some help in making this ticket machine code work. I can do it using if, else if and else, and I have seen it done with a while loop. However whenever I am trying to run it as an object I either get and error because of the print ticket at the bottom of the code, or build successful and no ticket. Here is my code

```
package ticketmachine;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class TicketMachine {
    private int price;
    private int change;
    private int balance;

public int getPrice(){
    return price;
}

public int getBalance(){
    return balance;
}

public TicketMachine (int ticketCost) {
    price = ticketCost;
    change = 0;
    balance = 0;
}

public void insertMoney (int amount){
    balance = balance + amount;
}    

public static void main(String[] args){ 

    String input1= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, " Insert a coin ");
    int ticketCost=Integer.parseInt(input1);


public void printTicket(){

    //Simulate the printing of a ticket
    System.out.println("##################");
    System.out.println("# Ticket");
    System.out.println("# " + price + " pence.");
    System.out.println("##################");
    System.out.println();
}
}        
}
```

Comment: This is not valid Java code

Comment: I am confused, what is happening vs what you expect to happen?  Not sure if error or not, but you are missing a closing curly brace on your main method and have an extra on at the end of the class

Comment: @MaxPower. Thank you, I have added the curly brace, as per below, but all I am getting now is build successful, and not the ticket printing out with the values on it. I am not sure where I have gone wrong....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here now it prints it

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;


public class TicketMachine {
    private int price;
    private int change;
    private int balance;

    public int getPrice(){
        return price;
    }

    public int getBalance(){
        return balance;
    }

    public TicketMachine (int ticketCost) {
        price = ticketCost;
        change = 0;
        balance = 0;
    }

    public void insertMoney (int amount){
        balance = balance + amount;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String input1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, " Insert a coin ");
        int ticketCost = Integer.parseInt(input1);
        TicketMachine ticketMachine = new TicketMachine(ticketCost);
        ticketMachine.printTicket();
    }


    public void printTicket(){

        //Simulate the printing of a ticket
        System.out.println("##################");
        System.out.println("# Ticket");
        System.out.println("# " + this.price + " pence.");
        System.out.println("##################");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

You should really try to learn how OOP works. People say they don't understand what you need due to the fact that you aren't even calling that method that prints the thicket.

Comment: This is why I am asking, I am currently doing a 4 day session on introductory OOP to get onto a degree a program, this is something we were told to do. When I spoke to the tutor, he has said it does not work as long as he can see that we have tried to code Class, and that you have tried to call the methods you will be fine. However as discussed earlier I would like to know how this works using OOP and not just else, if and while loops. I apologise if looks like I am not trying to learn, but the opposite to that true. Thank you for looking at my post and replying I do appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The closing braces are wrong on your last two methods. Try:

```
    public static void main(String[] args){ 

        String input1= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, " Insert a coin ");
        int ticketCost=Integer.parseInt(input1);

    } //Here 
    public void printTicket(){

        //Simulate the printing of a ticket
        System.out.println("##################");
        System.out.println("# Ticket");
        System.out.println("# " + price + " pence.");
        System.out.println("##################");
        System.out.println();
    }

  } //Closing of the class.
```

Comment: Thank you for this, this has made the build successful. I still get the dialog box to insert the coins, however nothing happens after that. I want it to print the ticket, and I can't figure out how to do it.